# play as many sounds as loop count in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-vlc

I want the alarm.play() function to repeat for the number of loops and ring 10 times as in the example, but it just keeps ringing once every time I try or change it. How can I fix this? And does it make more sense to use for instead of while ?

```
import time
import vlc

alarm = vlc.MediaPlayer("path")
m=0

while m<=10:
   alarm.play()
   time.sleep(1)
   m +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just `stop` the alarm at the end of loop and befor stop it create loop for stop executing while the sound is playing

```
import time
import vlc

alarm = vlc.MediaPlayer("path")
m = 0

while m <= 10:
    alarm.play()
    time.sleep(1)
    m += 1
    while alarm.is_playing():
        pass
    alarm.stop()
```